# Check if $date is equal to 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Tags: php, date

I want a logic if $due is equal to no date then I want data starting with 2000. My code below is not working.

```
if($due == '0000-00-00 00:00:00'){
    $due =  strtotime('2000-00-00 00:00:00');
}
```

Comment: Please provide the output of `var_dump($due);`

Comment: Where is this date coming from?

Comment: If you have retrieved that value from a database, it may be better to perform this logic in your query.  unless, that is, you have additional actions to take inside the `if()`

Comment: 0000-00-00 00:00:00 is coming from a database field.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If you are storing strtotime() in $due, then you need to compare it like that, too

```
if($due == strtotime('0000-00-00 00:00:00')){
    $due =  strtotime('2000-00-00 00:00:00');
}
```

or, more simply

```
if($due == 0){
    $due =  strtotime('2000-00-00 00:00:00');
}
```

but if $due is coming from your db as a string, you would want to strtotime() it:

```
$due = strtotime($due);
if($due == 0){
    $due =  strtotime('2000-00-00 00:00:00');
}
```

Be aware of timezones, though.  That is, strtotime('0000-00-00 00:00:00 UTC') != strtotime('0000-00-00 00:00:00 EST').  This could also break your compare.

Comment: strtotime('0000-00-00 00:00:00')
might return minus value, null, false depends on the PHP version

Answer (score 5):

I don't know why strtotime didnt work correctly for me. Probably it's because of time zone and other stuff.

As always fancy regular expressions works like a charm. I'm somehow addicted to it!

```
if(preg_match("/0{4}/" , $dbDateField))
{
    // no its not acceptable
}
else
{
    //ok
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is an old question but this answer may help somebody

strtotime returns a timestamp on success, FALSE otherwise.

```
$test = strtotime($due);  
$due  = (!$test || $test < 0) ? '2000-00-00 00:00:00' : $due;

unset($test);
```

regards.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that you are comparing the values in the same format. With what you currently have, on of three things will happen:

- If `$due` is an `int`, the string you are comparing it with `0000-00-00 00:00:00` will be converted to an `int`, which will result in `0`, and `$due` will be compared with `0`. This will only result in a match if `$due === 0`.
- If `$due` is a `bool`, the string will be converted to a `bool`, which will result in `TRUE`, and you will only get a match if `$due === TRUE`.
- If `$due` is any other type, it will be converted to a string and the two will be compared as strings. You will only get a match if `$due === '0000-00-00 00:00:00'`.

If would say that you probably need to compare the values as integers. This means that you need to pass any strings through `strtotime()` - including `$due`, if it is a string. Since you do not show an example value of `$due` I cannot provide an exact working code.

Answer (score 0):

`strtotime(YourDate) != NULL` works fine too.

I was working on a DOB and DOM (Date of Marriage) section of a Database. Seems the NULL default saved a date as 0000-00-00. Which is kind of a stupid thing to be honest.

Or perhaps it was my stupidity to make the field a DATE field instead of making it a VARCHAR and hold the STRTOTIME value there.

```
<?php 
    if(strtotime($dates->dom) != NULL) 
    {
        echo '<a href="' . base_url() . 'dates/dom/' . $dates->dom . '">' . date('j F, Y',strtotime($dates->dom)) . '</a>';
    } 
    else 
    { 
        print 'Not Listed Yet';
    } ?></strong>
```

Answer (score 0):

i would like to suggest simplest form

```
if(!$due)
        $due =  strtotime('2000-00-00 00:00:00');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution to check if datetime field in database (**mysql**) is null or `'0000-00-00 00:00:00'`

selecting all with starttime is null or '0000-00-00 00:00:00' and  endtime is not ( null or '0000-00-00 00:00:00')

At database end

```
select * from table where IFNULL(MONTH(starttime),0) >= 1 and IFNULL(MONTH(endtime),0) < 1;
```

at **php** end

```
if((int)$starttime && !(int)$endtime){  ///  }
```